# What is the distribution of $X|W=w$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent random variables with uniform distribution between $0$ and $1$, that is, have joint density $f_{xy}(x, y) = 1$, if x $\in$ $[0,1]$ and y $\in [0,1]$ and $f_{xy} (x, y) = 0$, cc. Let $W = (X + Y) / 2$:

What is the distribution of $X|W=w$?

I started considering something like this: $X|W = (x +y)/2$

But I stucked. I dont know how to begin.

Any idea? Hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conditional pdf is given by
$$f_{X | W = w}(x) =
\frac {f_{X, W}(x, w)} {f_W(w)}.$$
$f_W$ is the pdf of a sum of two independent uniformly distributed r.v.:
$$f_W(w) = 4 w \left[0 < w \leq \frac 1 2 \right] +
 4 (1 - w) \left[\frac 1 2 < w < 1 \right].$$
The transformation $(x,w) = (x, (x + y)/2)$ maps the square $0 < x < 1 \land 0 < y < 1$ to the parallelogram $0 < x < 1 \land 0 < 2 w - x < 1$ and has the Jacobian $\partial(x, w)/\partial(x, y) = 1/2$. The [transformed pdf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Multiple_variables) is
$$f_{X, W}(x, w) = 2 \,[0 < x < 1 \land 0 < 2 w - x < 1] = \\
2 \left[ 0 < w \leq \frac 1 2 \land 0 < x < 2 w \right] +
 2 \left[ \frac 1 2 < w < 1 \land 2 w - 1 < x < 1 \right].$$
Consider what $f_{X | W = w}$ simplifies to when $w < 1/2$ and when $w > 1/2$.

Comment: How did you found out f_{w}? I found 2w.

Comment: Start with finding the cdf: if $0 \leq w \leq 1/2$, then $\operatorname P(Y < 2 w - X)$ requires integrating $f_{X, Y}$ over the triangle with vertices $(0, 0), (2 w, 0), (0, 2w)$, giving $(2 w)^2/2$. (In fact, there is a known formula for an $n$-fold convolution of unit pulses.)

Answer (score 1):

$$X = 2W-Y$$

So,

$$X_c = (X|W=w) = (2w-Y_c) $$

Hence, $X_c$ should also be uniform from $[\max(2w-1,0),\min(2w,1)]$.

---

EDIT: Here is an argument for why $X_c$ will also be uniform over its domain.

$$P(X=x_1|W=w) = \frac{P(X=x_1 \& W=w)}{P(W=w)} = \frac{P(X=x_1 \& Y=2w-x_1)}{P(W=w)}$$
Since $X$ and $Y$ are independent, this becomes:

$$P(X=x_1|W=w) = \frac{P(X=x_1)P(Y=2w-x_1)}{P(W=w)}$$

If $2w-x_1 <0 $ or $2w-x_1>1$, the density above becomes $0$.

But otherwise, it will stay exactly the same if we replace $x_1$ by $x_2$ (such that both satisfy $0 \leq 2w-x \leq 1$). Hence, $X_c$ and $Y_c$ should remain uniform over their valid domains.

Comment: Thanks @RohitPandey but how $X_{c}= (2w - Y)$?

Comment: $X_c$ is $X$ conditional on $W=w$. Since by definition, $X+Y=2W$, if you tell me $W=w$, $X_c$ should be $2w-Y$

Comment: Humm. So it just enough to use $X=2W - Y$? If I want to calculate something like: $P(X<1/2)= P(Y>2w-1/2)$? Right?

Comment: These variables will remain uniform, only their domains will shift (for example, if $W=1$, the domain of $X_c$ becomes $[1,1]$; if $W=0.9$, the domain becomes $[0.8,1]$). Hence, you can calculate anything you like about them, given they are simply uniform over some domain.

Comment: Really really nice! Thanks!

Comment: @DiogoBastos added explanation for why $X_c$ and $Y_c$ must remain uniform.

Comment: Just the symmetry between $X$ and $Y$ is not sufficient though. Suppose we had $W = X Y$, then $f_{X | W = w}(x)$ wouldn't be a constant. The difference is that the jacobian of the transformation isn't constant in that case. Also, writing $\operatorname P(X = x)$ is problematic, the probability of a continuous r.v. taking a given value is zero.

Comment: @Maxim - I never said $P$ was a probability :)

Comment: Yes, yes, very funny, everyone can see the edit history. Notice that if you interpret $\operatorname P$ as the value of a pdf at a point, your last formula is incorrect: $f_X$ and $f_Y$ only take values $0$ or $1$, and $f_W = 4 w$ when $0 < w \leq 1/2$. But you need $2 w$ in the denominator. This is precisely because you're ignoring the jacobian.

Comment: Haha, it was a joke my man, I know you can see the edit history. Edit apart, my statement still stands if you take it literally. Feel free to improve the answer or add a new one.

Comment: Seriously, if you add an answer showing how to incorporate the Jacobian, I'll be the first to upvote.